Extracting structured data from user query
I want to extract structured data from the query provided by the user.
For example,
user query: I need data for females above the age of 3
output : {
min_age: 3,
max_age: None,
sex: female
}
These are few of the specific parameters that I require along with others.
I have tried using llama2, llama3 and gemma but i am facing the issue of hallucination
Also if a specific value is not given I want it to return 'None'
Is there any way I can achieve this using LLMs from ollama.
I have tried extracting the values one by one but I am not able to get the desired output
